# String variable contain string plus GET-variable

Tags: php, string, get

I want the value of `$queryText` is `"field = 'Peter'"`
How can I do that?

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = $_GET['name']";

echo $queryText;
```

Comment: I expect `$queryText` is a string that open and close by quotation mark
ie `$queryText = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do the following

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = '" . $_GET['name'] . "'";

echo $queryText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using your code:

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = $_GET[name]";

echo $queryText;
```

The single quotes around your array key cause an error. Removing them allows your code to work as expected.

There are alternative ways to do this:

1) Concatenation

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = " . $_GET['name'];

echo $queryText;
```

2) `sprintf()`

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = sprintf("field = %s", $_GET['name']);

echo $queryText;
```

3) Curly braces

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = {$_GET['name']}";

echo $queryText;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate as below:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
   $queryText = "$key = $value"; 
   echo $queryText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as John's code, you can also use yours, like this:

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = {$_GET['name']}";

echo $queryText;
```

or even:

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = ".$_GET['name'];

echo $queryText;
```

using string concatenation.

If you take away the `'` completely in the `GET` variable, that will also work:

```
$_GET['name'] = "Peter";
$queryText = "field = $_GET[name]";

echo $queryText;
```